# Start script on boot up?

Tags: 12.04, gnome, bash, scripts, init.d

I want to run a script when the system starts. The script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
gnome-terminal --tab -t "MyPC" -e "sh -c 'nohup firefox & nohup gedit & bash'" --tab -t "MYPC2" -e "sh -c 'ls -al;ls; bash'" > /home/user/gnome
```

So I copied my script to `/etc/init.d` and ran `update-rc.d boot-up defaults`

`boot-up` is name of my script.

Now, when I restart, the gnome-terminal is not opening (as wriiten in script), though I can see `/home/user/gnome` file being created which is empty.

I tried other methods like putting it in `/etc/rc.local` to no avail.

The only way the script runs is when I add it through `startup-Applications`.

Any idea How to make it work??

I am using Ububutu 12.04

Comment: duplicate: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/174314/4667 -- go there first, there are some answers

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cron`. `cron` allows you to set scheduled tasks in Linux.

```
crontab -e
@reboot <path-to-script>/boot-up #add to end of file
```